# C++ - Function template specialization not being called

Tags: c++, function, templates, character, specialization

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
bool validate(const T& minimum, const T& maximum, const T& testValue)
{
    return testValue >= minimum && testValue <= maximum;
}

template<>
bool validate<const char&>(const char& minimum, const char& maximum, const char& testValue)
{
    // Allows comparisons with char arguments, ignoring case    
    // Localize by calling previously defined function
    return validate(toupper(minimum), toupper(maximum), toupper(testValue));
}
```

The first template is used for any inputted types, and the specialization is for literal characters. The code compiles and runs with a main.cpp to test it, but after testing, I found that the specialization isn't being called. It calls the main template. I can't figure out why.

Comment: you shouldn't specialize for `<const char&>` case, but for `<char>`, the best would be not to specialize at all, and provide a non-template function overload

Comment: When I tried that I get a compiler error:

error: template-id 'validate<char>' for 'bool validate(char, char, char)' does not match any template declaration

Unfortunately, because this is a homework assignment, I cannot change the code in the main.cpp. I have to use template specialization.

Comment: if `T=char` then the parameters shall remain `const char&`

Comment: Code behaved as expected after! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `template <> bool validate<const char&>` specialization is picked by a compiler when type template parameter `T` from the primary template is deduced or specified explicitly to be `const char&`. For a call `validate('a', 'b', 'c')`, `T` is deduced to be `char`, and this doesn't match what the specialization expects.

Either provide a specialization for `char` (that is, not `const char&`):

```
template <>
bool validate<char>(const char& minimum, const char& maximum, const char& testValue)
{
    return validate(toupper(minimum), toupper(maximum), toupper(testValue));
}
```

or define the overload as a non-template:

```
bool validate(char minimum, char maximum, char testValue)
{
    return validate(toupper(minimum), toupper(maximum), toupper(testValue));
}
```

Comment: That was very informative. Thank you for explaining that process to me.